# Regarding pointwise convergence

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I came across the following function that is supposed to converge pointwise to the zero function. But I cannot understand how.

$$
f_{n}(t) = 
\begin{cases}
  n^2t,&0\le t\le\frac1n\\
  n^2\left(\frac2n-t\right),&\frac1n<t\le\frac2n\\
  0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

This is triangular function that becomes taller as $n \to \infty$, while maintaining a unit area $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{n}(t)dt = 1$.

What I cannot understand is that in this sequence of functions $f_{n}$, the points between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2n}$ do not converge. Then how can this sequence of functions be said to converge pointwise to the zero function.

Comment: For any fixed $x>0$, the number $f_n(x)$ will eventually become zero after $n$ will be so big that $x>\frac{2}{n}$. The number $\frac{1}{n}$ is changing.

Comment: @PeterFranek: Why does a changing point affect the pointwise convergence property? So if I were to modify the defintion of the above function as the following, then the functio is not longer pointwise convergent, right?

$$
f_{n}(t) = 
\begin{cases}
  n^{2} \left(t + \frac{1}{n}\right), & -\frac{1}{n} \le t \le 0 \\
  - n^{2} \left(t - \frac{1}{n}\right), & 0 < t \le \frac{1}{n} \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Your function is still pointwise convergent. You can define it arbitrarily on $(-\frac{1}{n},0)$ and zero elsewhere and it will be convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $0<x<1$. Choose $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ large enough so that $\frac2m<x$. Then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\ge m$, so $\langle f_n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\to 0$.

What you’re missing, I think, is that as $n$ increases, the base of the triangle shrinks in such a way that the lower right corner approaches the origin. Thus, the triangle moves off any fixed $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, by the same argument can we say that the following function is also pointwise convergent?

$
f_{n}(t) = 
\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \frac{1}{n} & 0 < t < \frac{1}{n} \\
    0 & Otherwise
  \end{array} \right.
$

Comment: @siva82kb: Yes. In fact, the argument even shows that $$f_n(t)=\begin{cases}n,&\text{if }0<t<\frac1n\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ is pointwise convergent to the zero function!

Comment: @Brain M. Scott: Oh, sorry I really meant to write the function you have mentioned in your comment. :) What about the following? Now that the point zero has been made to include the point that blows up, does it change things?

$
f_{n}(t) = 
\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    n & |t| \leq \frac{1}{n} \\
    0 & Otherwise
  \end{array} \right.
$

Comment: @siva82kb: Yes, that does change things, because then $f_n(0)=n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so that the sequence of functions doesn’t converge pointwise at $x=0$ at all. It does converge pointwise to $0$ everywhere else, though.

Comment: So, it seems to me that if the point that blows up is not fixed then there is pointwise convergence. The two functions we discussed are, in essence, just shifted version of each other, and this shift can change the property of pointwise convergence.

Comment: @siva82kb: It’s not quite that simple. It’s not hard to come up with a sequence of functions $f_n$ with isosceles triangular peaks whose bases run from $-\frac1n$ to $\frac2n$ for even $n$ and from $-\frac2n$ to $\frac1n$ for odd $n$ and which are tall enough so that $h_n(0)\ge n$ for all $n$; this sequence converges pointwise to $0$ at every $x\ne 0$, but it doesn’t converge pointwise at $0$ at all, even though the no two triangles have a peak at the same $x$-coordinate.